# KML and delete old KMLs files

Tags: kml

Exists a way for i can delete the temporary places in google earth before add new placemarks using a kml file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to delete before adding a new file, but you could set up a network link that points to the file and then set up refresh interval or expires settings.
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink